# explain why the following definition is not equivalent to the definition of the limit of function f

Tags: limits, definition

Let $f:(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a given function. Explain how the following definition is not equivalent to the definition of the limit

$\lim\limits_{x \to x_0} f(x) = L$

of $f$ at $x_0 \in [0,1]$ .

For any $\epsilon \gt 0$ there exists $\delta \gt 0$ such that for all $x \in (0,1)$ and $|x-x_0| \leq \delta$, one has $|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon$ .

I don't see the difference between this definition and the actual definition of the limit of a function. Could someone help me out with this?

Please and thank you.

Comment: You have to exclude $x=x_0$, that's why the standard definition has $0<|x-x_0|≤\delta$.  If, say, your function is $f(x)=1$ for $x\neq \frac 12$ and $f\left( \frac 12\right) =0$ then $\lim_{x\to \frac 12}f(x)=1$ with the usual definition, but not with your definition.

Comment: Wait so do you mean to say that it’s suppose to be $0 \lt |x- x_0| \lt \delta$ And not less than or equal to delta?

Comment: That's not a meaningful difference.  Think it through...you can always modify $\delta$ according to which definition you favor.  But the $>0$ requirement has real meaning.